cz.habarta.typescript-generator error: cannot load class
I'm building a Java Spring boot application, and after adding a client module, I want to autogenerate my DTOs as TypeScript Interfaces using TypeScript Generator Maven Plugin. My issue is that after setting up Client POM and plugin configuration, when I try to run the build I'm getting an error:

Failed to execute goal cz.habarta.typescript-generator:typescript-generator-maven-plugin:2.34.976:generate (generate-typescript) on project tflow-client: Execution generate-typescript of goal cz.habarta.typescript-generator:typescript-generator-maven-plugin:2.34.976:generate failed: No input classes found.

There is a block of code that configures TypeScript generator inside my client POM:
 <plugin>
          <groupId>cz.habarta.typescript-generator</groupId>
          <artifactId>typescript-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${typescript-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>generate-typescript</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <configuration>
                <outputKind>module</outputKind>
                <jsonLibrary>jackson2</jsonLibrary>
                <classPatterns>
                  <pattern>com.matejgeljic.taskflow.domain.dto.*</pattern>
                </classPatterns>
                <outputFile>src/main/tsx/src/generated/bff-api.ts</outputFile>
                <outputFileType>implementationFile</outputFileType>
                <stringQuotes>singleQuotes</stringQuotes>
                <mapEnum>asEnum</mapEnum>
                <nonConstEnums>true</nonConstEnums>
                <optionalProperties>useSpecifiedAnnotations</optionalProperties>
                <optionalAnnotations>org.springframework.lang.Nullable</optionalAnnotations>
                <generateSpringApplicationClient>true</generateSpringApplicationClient>
                <generateSpringApplicationInterface>true</generateSpringApplicationInterface>
                <restNamespacing>perResource</restNamespacing>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>cz.habarta.typescript-generator</groupId>
              <artifactId>typescript-generator-spring</artifactId>
              <version>${typescript-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>

I also have a dependency on a server module in the same pom:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>tflow-server</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

My folder structure looks like this:
tflow-client
-src
-pom.xml
tflow-server
-src
-pom.xml

Before I get ClasNotFoundException in the console, I would see this log:

Running TypeScriptGenerator version 2.34.976
Loading class org.springframework.lang.Nullable
Scanning classpath
Scanning finished in 2.60 seconds. Total number of classes: 31617.
Found 5 classes matching pattern.

Has anyone had similar issues in the past? Thank you a lot
